# Ajax request after success, returns response session timeout

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

```
$("#myselect").click(function () {
            var ID = $("#myselect option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("TemplateWindowManage", "Template")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: ID }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('1');
                    $("#TemplateDesc").html(response);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('2');
                    $("#TemplateDesc").html(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

when the click event fires, ajax request is sucessfull. but the response is 'Session Timout'. And it actually do not hit the server side TemplateWindowManage Action.

If the request is successfull, it should bring some data from server side, but if it doesn't go to server, how could it be `success`? 
and why `Session Timeout` is showing?

**Additional:**
Sometimes it goes to the server side, and sometimes not. When goes then returns data accurately and my purpose is done. I have put my `SessionState='InProc' and TimeOut = '120'`

Comment: I delete my answer, I tried this in my projects and it was not valid. I upvote your question to have better visibility, also it will be good to be added in your question that "some time it goes to the server side". If the problem is timeout, you can try to turn up the timeout bigger in the ajax request. Did you try this already ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question little bit. I have kept session timeout for 120 min

Comment: @AbdurRahim The timeout in ajax request is in milliseconds. So 120 will be equal to 0.12 seconds. Did you try to increase the timeout of the ajax request ?

Comment: I gave the value in web.config. under <system.Web>

Comment: @haim770 but this is giving me the exact value!! and I want the selected option value. so, how only ID will give me the selected value?

Comment: @AbdurRahim, Perhaps your version would work as well, but the normal jQuery way to do this is `$('myselect').val()`. It will work because when the browser is requested for the value of `HTMLSelectElement`, it *will* return the value of the current selected `<option>`.